# Emphasize 'Only when allowed' in contrast to NOT being allowed

Tags: translation, antonyms

In Dutch I can let the user choose between (a software setting):

> Alleen indien NIET toegestaan
>   Alleen indien WEL toegestaan

for which I think the English translation should be:

> Only when NOT allowed
>   Only when allowed

But as you can see, that translation misses the visual emphasis (capitals) for the positive choice.
Is there something I can do with the translation that would let me use emphasis for both choices?

Notes:

1) This is a configuration setting with a 3rd choice: *N/a*

2) I do not have the option of making this (much) longer like in

> Only when overtime is NOT allowed
>   Only when overtime IS allowed

That is exactly the issue, it seems: there is no noun to refer to.

Comment: If you're determined to have a word you can capitalise for "visual emphasis", consider *Only when **EXPRESSLY** allowed* (or ***EXPLICITLY** permitted,* etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suggest you make that an answer

Comment: I don't fully understand your context. Are you talking about two possible values for a single configuration setting? The first thing that comes to mind for me there is a choice between "blacklisting" and "whitelisting" (for a web browser, say). In that context, "blacklist" would mean *You can visit **all sites except those listed as forbidden***, whereas "whitelist" would mean *You can visit **only those sites listed as permitted***. Is that the kind of thing you're asking about?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Correct, *two possible values for a single configuration setting*.

Comment: I don't think this is really a "Learning English" type of question. You might do better asking on [SO User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) for this sort of thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes I had considered that already. If it does not work out here, I'll move it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the sentences parallel by changing "NOT allowed" such as

> Only when FORBIDDEN
>
> Only when ALLOWED

or perhaps from your context

> Only when DISABLED
>
> Only when ENABLED